# O meu ImageView não aparece no meu telemóvel

Tags: android, xamarin

Criei um Layout e uma Activity para esse Layout.

No Layout só tenho uma ImageView com uma imagem png que está localizada nos Resources/Drawables.

Quando faço Debug na Aplicação a ImageView não aparece no ecrã do meu telemóvel.

Este o meu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:gravity="center"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:visibility="visible">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350.0dp"
    android:layout_height="279.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/OpeningLogo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Este é o código da minha Activity:

```
namespace **********
{
    [Activity(Label = "xxxxxxxxx", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Logo")]
    public class OpeningActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Opening);

            Intent GoToLogin = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            this.Finish();
            StartActivity(GoToLogin);
        }
    }
}
```

Se quiserem que eu coloque mais dados digam.

Desde já obrigado.

Tenho uma cópia desta pergunta no StackOverflow Inglés, se me derem a resposta lá eu depois coloco aqui e vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheesebaron respondeu-me com isto no Stack Overflow Inglés, já tenho a resposta.

```
namespace *********
{
    [Activity(Label = "xxxxxxxxx", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Logo")]
    public class OpeningActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Opening);

            await Task.Delay(5000);

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

O problema era que eu não dava tempo para a imagem aparecer.

Answer (score 0):

Retire a linha :

```
 this.Finish();
```